# C# LINQ, Summation and Type system - What is the int? type

Tags: c#, linq, types, type-conversion

I'm doing work with LINQ in C#. Part of the code requires a Sum down a column.

```
SomeTable.Where( CONDITION ).Sum( Entity => Entity.IntColumn );
```

This returns a type of int? rather than an int as the table's column's type is also of the int? form.

My questions are thus:
 What is the int? or double? e&. type?
- What is the best practice for converting or casting those types into their useable int or double e&. counter parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int?, double?, etc are nullable types. Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type, and an additional null value.

Each instance of a nullable type has two public read-only properties:

`HasValue`
HasValue is of type bool. It is set to true when the variable contains a non-null value.

`Value`
Value is of the same type as the underlying type. If HasValue is true, Value contains a meaningful value. If HasValue is false, accessing Value will throw a InvalidOperationException.

```
int? x = 10;
if (x.HasValue)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Undefined");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx#Y431

Answer (score 4):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

You can use `myInt.HasValue` to see if there is a value set or if it is null and then `myInt.Value` to retrieve the int when it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select one column of a numeric type:
`SomeTable.Where( CONDITION ).Sum(Entity => Entity.NumericColumn);`
Then the sum will be of  that numeric type.

Comment: Is it not kosher to use it as Sum( Entity => Entity.IntColumn ) instead of Select( ... ).Sum() ? ( as that is what I'm doing )